# How to save XML Data in String form in HSQLDB table column

Tags: xml, hsqldb

I have a webservice client which calls  Webservice-A for xml data in string form. The client receives the xml data in string. The thread needs to push the same xml data in string form to another Webservice-B.
What we need is to save this xml data in hsqldb table column before pushing it to Webservice-B via thread.  I checked the supported data types of HSQLDB which includes XML but when i set the datatype of column as XML, the table cannot be created.
Please guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create the table with a LONGVARCHAR or CLOB column and store the XML data there.

For your usage you just use the setString() method of PreparedStatement and getString() method of RasultSet to insert and retrieve the XML.

Only if you need to access the fields or create the XML data, you use the getSQLXML() method of ResultSet and createSQLXML() method of Connection.

Comment: I have saved the xml string in LONGVARCHAR but now its showing some performance issue in retrieving data back. Kindly tell me how to convert String data to clob and save it in HSQLDB because HSQLDB is not supporting dbConn.createClob(); method

Comment: The createClob() is actually supported. But you don't need it and can use the method you are currently using to insert the string data into the database. You just need to do `ALTER TABLE <tablename> ALTER COLUMN <colname> SET DATA TYPE CLOB` to convert the existing column to CLOB.